# What should be included in "good practices" for Tikz 101

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have been making graphics (mostly flow graphs) for my presentations, lately, using Powerpoint and most recently LucidChart. I kind of avoided using Latex for this purpose as I had a feeling that its not going to be easy. Anyways, now I have decided to learn and master this powerful tool but going through the manual ,as I expected, is not a good idea for a jump start. 
So I was wondering if I can get some good advices that I should flow while making graphics in my beamer presentations. One thing that I have noticed that one needs to specify coordinates for everything. Is it a good idea to first draw a grid on slide and then proceed?

So please contribute practices that you have found to be useful for generating graphics using tikz package. I am looking forward to hear what experts have to say in this regard

Comment: You can also use relative coordinates.  For a path use ++(x,y).  For coordinates (not part of a path) you can use the calc library ($(A)+(x,y)$).  For nodes you can use [above right=1em] (for example) or [xshift=x,yshift=y].

Comment: Make  the tikz graphics as separate files and use only the PDFs in the main document. Advantages: faster compilation (significant for long presentations with many images),  better focus on frame contents and document structure if the source is not bloated everywhere with  distracting tikz code, less risk of  break something accidentally and easier debugging in case of disaster.

Comment: I don't think that this question should be tagged `beamer`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

- **Use styles.** Whenever you have color, shape, fonts, alignment,  define a TikZ style for it and use it. Don't apply such formatting details to nodes or edges, apply the style. A single point for consistent customizing.
- **Inherit styles.** Start with a base node style (font family, base color), define styles which use base styles and add size or color or alignment - no repetitions, single points for global changes.
- **Use macros.** Have consistent TikZ commands or command sequences, which can be reused and changed.
- **Use constants.** For every value needed, such as distances, declare a constant via `\def` or a TikZ length command, so you can use it repeatedly and adjust it at a single source code position to customize a whole drawing or a lot of drawings.
- **Use relative positions.** So you can change a reference coordinate, and all other positions will be automatically adjusted.
- **Let TikZ calculate for you.** Once certain points such as corners are defined, use TikZ syntax to define a relative positions such as middle points and intersection points. Let TikZ do the geometry for you. If you change the reference points or image size, all will automatically adjust.
- **Name everything.** Especially in non-trivial drawings, edges between named coordinates are much clearer to read than using coordinate numbers everywhere.
- **Use scopes.** Don't repeat things - if you cannot apply a bunch of properties via styles, use a scope to apply settings to a whole area of a drawing. Also here, it's easy to change that part at a single position.
- **Use loops.** If you need to repeat things, benefit from the power of TikZ `\foreach` loops to reduce the amount of repeated code.
- **Don't nest TikZ pictures.** There is always another way to do it.

Comment: So before I start exploring these pointers, I have one basic question. Consider a standard beamer slide with a tile n slide number. How should I fix rest of the available area for the graphic. The idea is that I first assign a fixed space to my graphic in every slide and then proceed from there. Right now I am trying to insert the right size of grid in my code so that from there I can know the coordinates (I don't know yet how can I make tikz compute the coordinates for me). Is this idea of fixing space sound right?

Comment: I want to replicate my graphics so that by changing colors of my component blocks, I can give an impression of animation. I normally do this by making multiple copies of every slide and then change colors of text to send items in background and foreground. Now I want to do the same with my block diagrams

Comment: @NAASI: Beamer has a very elegant way of sending elements to "the background and foreground". You can use `\only<...>{...}` or other variants. Why don't you create a new question with what you to do?

Comment: What is a "TikZ length command"? When I need a constant, I use `\pgfmathsetmacro`, but I think that won't let me define real lengths.

Comment: @mrc It is `\pgfmathsetlength` look for it in the manual

Answer (score 23):

- **Don't try to use everything from Stefan Kottwitz's otherwise [mostly excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297029/) in your first TikZ graphic.**

  More generally, don't try to learn everything at once. Even if your initial code is longer, less flexible and harder to maintain.

  - When you have sufficient knowledge to produce a picture, add *one* complication as appropriate e.g. a loop or a style.
  - When you can do basic loops or styles without too much trouble, add *one* more thing.
- **Don't use `\def`** unless (1) you cannot use a LaTeX command creation macro (`\newcommand*`, `\newcommand`, `\newlength`, `\newcounter` etc.) **and** (2) you understand why you need `\def` **and** (3) you understand the consequences of using `\def`.

Not specific to TikZ:

- annotate your code so that you can tell what it is for when you inevitably forget later.

  [At least, I inevitably forget.]

Comment: When you say "understand the consequences of using \def", do you mean anything more significant than the fact that it silently overwrites existing commands? I don't see what other problems it has.

Comment: @HoodChatham That is rather a major consequence, is it not? A bit like saying, do you mean anything more significant than the fact that it will destroy the house? I don't see what other problems striking a match when I smell gas has.

Comment: I agree that it's extremely important, I just thought that since it only takes one simple sentence to explain, it would be better for completeness to include it. I see now that in my original comment I said "more significant than". I agree that that was a poor choice of words -- I was thinking of conceptual significance (difficulty to explain), not practical significance.

Comment: Even worse that  destroy the house: `\def\con1{Able Archer 83}` **;)**

Comment: @Fran ?? What does that do?

Comment: @HoodChatham It isn't that simple, it seems to me. If you just say it will overwrite an existing command, people don't necessarily think about commands they rely on implicitly but never type and they certainly don't think about things like environments. It is really only simple if you are already reasonably familiar with LaTeX. But then you probably don't need the explanation....

Comment: @cfr Yeah I guess you're right. For instance, no one ever uses the command \span, but if someone doing linear algebra could quite easily say \def\span{\textup{Span}} and all sorts of things would immediately break (of course, this is a less insidious example than some because you could probably find a command to overwrite that isn't used on every compile).

I guess I'm having a common problem -- if you understand something, it's very hard to accurately model what it's like not to understand it. This is why teaching is really hard...

Comment: @HoodChatham Very hard ;). It is far from obvious that `\table` is required by the `table` environment, for example. Or think about `\def\list...`!

Comment: @cfr A nuclear war. It is just cryptic black humor: Some time ago (1983) the NATO played a war game (Able Archer) simulating a DEFCON1. The funny was that URSS thought that it was not a game, so were closer 
than ever to the nuclear war since Cuba missile crisis (1962). An example of a dangerous play with a def[ense condition]. (Do not try to see any relationship  with LaTeX, at some point of the sleeplessness I gain  this weird no-sense of no-humor).

Comment: @Fran Thanks for the explanation ;). You mean USSR ...?

Comment: @cfr oh, yes, USSR of course (URSS is the Spanish acronym).

Answer (score 11):

**1. Start with basics**

Place named nodes and draw lines between them:

```
\node (a) at (1,5) {$A$};
\node (b) at (2,3) {$B$};
\draw (a) -- (b);
```

This way you can make any simple graph, you just need to get your coordinates right (at this point, it is better to make a quick drawing on paper first, and get the coordinates this way)

**2. Improve style as you need**

Tikz has many styling functions, for line width, colors, etc. Some more useful than others. Look for anything you think would improve the drawing, and you'll find it. You'll remember the most useful ones quickly.

**3. Improve your code to make it more efficient**

Don't want to give exact numbers for coordinates? There are many ways to achieve relative placement! Learn about `.north`, `.south` placement, or use calculations in coordinates.

You use copy-paste too much for your own taste? Learn about styles, macros, use `scope`s or the most-powerfull `\foreach` loops.

You use beamer? Learn how to make overlays painlessly using e.g. `\only` or `\alt`

You'll end up having a much shorter code, much faster to write, so you can quickly make, say, a nice animation of an algorithm running on a graph.

Comment: For defining a position `\coordinate` is often better than `\node`.  You can then use `\node` or `node` later to add the label.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: As far as I  understand, \coordinate can always be replaced by a node with empty label, but  the other way round is less easy (e.g., when you want your label inside the node, and edges arrive precisely at the border). So for starting I think `\node` is enough, but of course in the long run it is useful to learn about `\coordinate` to improve the code.

Comment: Indeed, I only said "often", which of course depends on what you typical use case is.