# Page alignment forced to center using tikz-dependency

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, formatting, pdftex, linguistics

I'm fairly new to `tikz-dependency`,`tikz` and `pgfplot` and I am trying to use it for plotting the output of several dependency parsers. However whenever I render a document using PDFLateX or LatexMk I end up with the following output with the graph centered in an odd position.

[image: Misaligned dependency graph]
The code to generate such an output is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{dependency}
    \begin{deptext}[column sep=0.2cm]
        The \& old \& car \& broke \& down \& in \& the \& car \& park \\
    \end{deptext}
\deproot{4}{root}
\depedge{3}{1}{det}
\depedge{3}{2}{amod}
\depedge{4}{3}{nsubj}
\depedge{4}{5}{compound:prt}
\depedge{9}{6}{case}
\depedge{9}{7}{det}
\depedge{9}{8}{compound}    
\depedge{4}{9}{nmod:in}
\end{dependency}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Stanford Output Sentence 1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I'm using:

- Mac OS X 10.13.2
- pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) 
  or
- LatexMk 4.52c with the same issue with both build tools.

The caption leads me to believe the figure is centered but I guess some part of how I declare the `tikzpicture` might be wrong. I'm not sure how to solve this and I hope someone else has come across this before and workout out how to fix this.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `\centering` inside the `tikzpicture`?

Comment: You do not need the `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}`, just dive straight in with `\begin{dependency}...`.  Remove those two lines results in a centered picture.

Answer (score 1):

Simply removing the `tikzpicture` from your code results in centered diagram:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{dependency}
    \begin{deptext}[column sep=0.2cm]
      The \& old \& car \& broke \& down \& in \& the \& car \& park \\
    \end{deptext}
    \deproot{4}{root}
    \depedge{3}{1}{det}
    \depedge{3}{2}{amod}
    \depedge{4}{3}{nsubj}
    \depedge{4}{5}{compound:prt}
    \depedge{9}{6}{case}
    \depedge{9}{7}{det}
    \depedge{9}{8}{compound}
    \depedge{4}{9}{nmod:in}
  \end{dependency}
  \caption{Stanford Output Sentence 1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Indeed you should not include a `dependency` inside a `tikzpicture` and as the `dependency` environment already creates a `tikzpicture` and nesting of `tikzpicture` environments does not behave well.  See [What should be included in "good practices" for Tikz 101](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297025/15925) for good `tikz` practices including not nesting.

By the way, you should not really be using `[!h]`: `figure`s are floats and designed to be moved around.  If you want your diagram at particular place in the text then you can use the `center` environment combined with `\captionof` from the `caption` package to add a caption.  See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/15925)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question with something that works well enough for my needs. I didn't know about the `usetikzlibrary{positioning}` command for my preamble. When I put that in and changed the first two lines of the figure to:

```
\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center]
```

then I got what I needed.

Comment: Also I got rid of \centering

Comment: While that sort of gets you what you're after, it is more or less by accident, and I have to say that the approach is entirely wrong. Andrew Swann's comment above is the correct answer: remove `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}`. The `dependency` environment is not supposed to be used inside a `tikzpicture`.