# Unable to increase the font size of the tikz text using \fontsize

Tags: fontsize, tikz-styles, article

I have submitted the code for the reference

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,gensymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

%\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}

%\usepackage{subfigure}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %added package
\usepackage{multirow,array, amsmath, caption, booktabs,amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url, lipsum}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,backref=true,linkcolor={black},anchorcolor={black},citecolor={black},urlcolor={blue},breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\usepackage[boxed,lined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\graphicspath{ {Images/} }
\linespread{1.1}
\usepackage[top=.8in, bottom=.8in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcommand\myrule{\par\smallskip\hrule\medskip}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,trees, decorations.markings, arrows, arrows.meta,positioning, shapes.arrows,shadows.blur}
\def\etal{\textit{et~al.}}
\def\eg{\textit{e.g.}}
\def\ie{\textit{i.e.}}
\def\etc{\textit{etc.}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%Road Map%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz,pgfgantt}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewenvironment{abstract}
 {\par\noindent\textbf{\abstractname \newline}\ \ignorespaces}
 {\par\medskip}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\nodetextx}[2]{$i_{#2}$}
\newcommand{\nodetextz}[2]{$o_#2$}
\newcommand{\nodetexth}[2]{$h_{#1,#2}$}
\makeatletter
\define@key{layer}{layercolor} {\def\nnlayercolor{#1}}
\makeatother

\tikzstyle{hiddencl}=[neuron, fill=\nnlayercolor, draw=black]
\newcommand{\hiddenlayercolor}[1][] { \layer[bias=true,nodeclass={hiddencl},#1] }

\tikzstyle{inputcl}=[neuron, fill=\nnlayercolor, draw=black]
\newcommand{\inputlayercolor}[1][] { \layer[bias=true,nodeclass={inputcl},#1] }

\tikzstyle{outputcl}=[neuron, fill=\nnlayercolor, draw=black]
\newcommand{\outputlayercolor}[1][] { \layer[bias=true,nodeclass={outputcl},#1] }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\sloppy

\begin{figure}
\centering
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, fit, positioning}
\tikzset{block11/.style={fill=yellow!20,draw, thick, text width=11cm,align=justify,inner sep=0.6cm},  font={\fontsize{45pt}{12}\selectfont},   line/.style={-latex}}
\tikzset{block1/.style={fill=yellow!20,draw, thick, text width=9cm,align=center,inner sep=0.6cm},  font={\fontsize{45pt}{12}\selectfont},   line/.style={-latex}}
\tikzset{block2/.style={fill=yellow!20,draw, thick, text width=9cm,align=left,inner sep=0.4cm},  font={\fontsize{45pt}{12}\selectfont},   line/.style={-latex}}
\tikzset{block/.style={fill=blue!15,draw, thick, text width=10cm,align=center,minimum width=11cm,minimum height = 4cm},font={\fontsize{45pt}{12}\selectfont},   
line/.style={-latex}}
\tikzset{blocks/.style={fill=yellow!20,draw, thick, text width=11cm,align=center,inner sep=0.8cm}, font={\fontsize{45pt}{12}\selectfont},  line/.style={-latex}}

%\newcommand{\midarrow}{\tikz \draw[-triangle 90] (0,0) -- +(-.1,0);}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[ellipse, draw,text width=15cm,fill=red!15,text centered,font={\fontsize{45pt}{12}\selectfont}] (w1) at (-3,9) {\textbf{XYZ} \\ \vspace{0.6cm} \textit{``qwerty werwe \\[0.4cm] quiet Guard?"} };
\node[ellipse, draw,minimum width = 30cm, minimum height = 15cm,fill=red!15,font={\fontsize{45pt}{12}\selectfont}] (w2) at (-3,-15) {};
\node[minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 0.5cm,text centered,font={\fontsize{45pt}{12}}] (p) at (-3,-9) {\textbf{Output}};
\node[block1] (q) at (-9,-12) {\textit{Bran}, \textbf{\textt{wrerw}}};
\node[block1,right=of q]  (r) {\textit{haue}, \textbf{\textt{dfs}}};
\node[block1,below=of r]at (-9,-13) (s) {\textit{you}, \textbf{\textt{sdf}}};
\node[block1,right= of s] (t) {\textit{bad}, \textbf{\textt{vdxv}}};
\node[block1,below= of t] at (-9,-16) (u) {\textit{quiet}, \textbf{\textt{dsf}}};
\node[block1,right=of u] (v) {\textit{Guard}, \textbf{\textt{sdf}}};
\node[rectangle, draw,minimum width =15cm, minimum height =14cm] (ik) at (30,8) {}; 
\node[minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 0.5cm,text centered,font={\fontsize{100pt}{12}\selectfont}] (a) at (30,14) { \textbf{Process}};
\node[blocks] (b) at (30,10) {\textit{fsdfsde \\[0.4cm] you sdf \\[0.2cm] sdf?}};
\node[blocks] (c) at (30,4) {\textit{wsd sdf u \\[0.4cm] dsfsdfsd  sdfsd}};
\node[rectangle, draw,minimum width =27cm, minimum height =22cm] (jk) at (31.14,-16) {};
\node[minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 0.5cm,text centered,font={\fontsize{45pt}{12}\selectfont}] (d) at (30,-6.4) {\textbf{Word egdf}};
\node[block11] (d) at (24.5,-10.28) {\textit{df} = [-0.106,\\[0.4cm] 0.789, -0.130]};
\node[block11,right=of d]  (e) {\textit{fdf} = [-0.211, \\[0.4cm]-0.094, -0.246]};
\node[block11,below=of e]at (24.5,-13) (f) {\textit{you} = [0.277, \\[0.4cm]-0.049,-0.477]};
\node[block11,right= of f] (g) {\textit{df} = [-0.014, \\[0.4cm]0.387, -0.348]};
\node[block11,below= of g] at (24.5,-19.5) (h) {\textit{dfd} = [0.184, \\[0.3cm]-0.025, -0.600]};
\node[block11,right=of h] (i) {\textit{Guardfd} = [0.211, \\[0.3cm]-0.324, -0.230]};
\node[rectangle, draw,minimum width =15cm, minimum height =35cm] (lk) at (60,-5) {};
\node[minimum width = 5cm, minimum height = 0.5cm,text centered,font={\fontsize{45pt}{12}\selectfont}] (j) at (60,11) {\textbf{dfgh}};
\node[block] (k) at (60,7) {fgh};
\node[block] (l) at (60, 1) {Bi-hjhn};
\node[block] (m) at (60,-5) {uyi};
\node[block] (n) at (60,-11) {yuir};
\node[block] (o) at (60,-17) {tyui};
\node[rectangle, draw,minimum width =52cm, minimum height =45cm] (oo) at (43,-5) {};
\draw[->, arrowhead=0.3in, line width=6pt] (w1) -- (17,9);
\draw[->, arrowhead=0.3in, line width=6pt] (30,1) -- (30,-5);
\draw[->, arrowhead=0.3in, line width=6pt] (jk) -- (52.5,-15.7);

\begin{scope}[very thick, every node/.style={sloped,allow upside down}]
  \draw [-, arrowhead=0.3in, line width=6pt](-3.5,-30)-- node {\midarrow} (60,-30);
  \draw[-, arrowhead=0.3in, line width=6pt] (60,-30)-- node {\midarrow} (60,-22.5);
  %\draw (4,2)-- node {\midarrow} (-4,2);
  \draw[<-, arrowhead=0.3in, line width=6pt] (-3.5,-22.5)-- node {\midarrow} (-3.5,-30);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{\textcolor{blue}{Drawere}}
\label{fig:Draweer}
\end{figure}




\end{document}
```

[image: output of the code]

Comment: This is... way too much code. Maybe reduce it to a minimal working example?

Comment: Also, post your actual code, backslash-[ won't compile in LaTeX.

Comment: I have used overleaf to compile it. And I am trying to increase the font size of the text present in the respective nodes.

Comment: Basic syntax: `\node at (0,0) {\Large text};`. Besides, there are some syntax such as `font={\fontsize{45pt}{12}}` that might interfere with what you want to edit. And, please, read about [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/140133)s and also [good practices for TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297025/140133). It is quite messy to read a code with too many commands, and also unrelated packages and commands.

Comment: Don't scale picture. Rather define smaller nodes.

Comment: `\fontsize{45pt}{12}` means letters 45pt (1.5cm) tall on lines that are 12pt apart. Do you really mean that???

Comment: Yes. after writing \fontsize{45pt}{12} the letter size are not increasing.

Comment: @FHZ yes I will make the corrections

Comment: Note that almost all opening and closing square brackets have a backslash before them. I don't know why this is, but it prevents proper compilation of your code if not parsed beforehand.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I have made the correction kindly check it now

Comment: The `arrowhead` option is deprecated code from the `arrows.meta` library. Instead of `->, arrowhead=0.3in` , you probably want to use `-{>[width=0.3in]}`. Instead of `\textt{}`, you probably mean `\texttt{}`. The macro `\midarrow` is not defined, since you commented out its defintion. Once you remove the `\resizebox` wrapper, you will see, that the text in the nodes is indeed as large as you want it to be.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, the \resizebox is used to fit the diagram in different places. Can you please help me with the running code so it will be easier for me?

Comment: With `\resizebox`, the image is scaled down. Therefore the font won't be as large as you state. But the `\fontsize` declaration works pretty well, which you can see if you remove one of those which will render the text in a much smaller font size. How should I help you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137861/discussion-between-avi007-and-jasper-habicht).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you face lies it the fact that the picture you defined using Ti*k*Z is huge and you try to scale it down using `\resizebox` which also will decrease the font size. You try to counter this behavior by increasing the font size. However, LaTeX doesn't allow you to increase the font size arbitrarily.

The best way to solve this would be to create a drawing with Ti*k*Z that uses relative (unitless) dimensions and therefore is scalable. Alas, since the `tikzpicture` you provide is already defined in a way that uses absolute dimensions, this surely would be a lot of work.

In order to provide a quick solution, you should load the pacakge `anyfontsize` which allows you to use `\fontsize` with any font size you want, even those that are not officially provided by the font you use.

Apart from that, there are still a lot of strange things in your code.

1. The `\fontsize` macro takes two arguments which are already parsed as pt. Therefore you can just integers here.
2. Instead of `\textt{}`, you probably want to write `\texttt[}`.
3. The option `arrowhead` is a deprecated option of the `arrows.meta` package. You should use `-{>[width=0.3in]}` instead of `->, arrowhead=0.3in`.
4. The macro `\midarrow` is not defined, since you commented it out in your code.

I corrected the above things, removed all the packages that are unnecessary for this example and added the Ti*k*Z library `shapes` but left the code untouched otherwise:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,trees, decorations.markings, arrows, arrows.meta,positioning, shapes.arrows,shadows.blur, shapes}

\tikzstyle{hiddencl}=[neuron, fill=\nnlayercolor, draw=black]
\newcommand{\hiddenlayercolor}[1][] { \layer[bias=true,nodeclass={hiddencl},#1] }

\tikzstyle{inputcl}=[neuron, fill=\nnlayercolor, draw=black]
\newcommand{\inputlayercolor}[1][] { \layer[bias=true,nodeclass={inputcl},#1] }

\tikzstyle{outputcl}=[neuron, fill=\nnlayercolor, draw=black]
\newcommand{\outputlayercolor}[1][] { \layer[bias=true,nodeclass={outputcl},#1] }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\sloppy

\begin{figure}
\centering
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, fit, positioning}
\tikzset{block11/.style={fill=yellow!20,draw, thick, text width=11cm,align=justify,inner sep=0.6cm},  font={\fontsize{45}{12}\selectfont},   line/.style={-latex}}
\tikzset{block1/.style={fill=yellow!20,draw, thick, text width=9cm,align=center,inner sep=0.6cm},  font={\fontsize{45}{12}\selectfont},   line/.style={-latex}}
\tikzset{block2/.style={fill=yellow!20,draw, thick, text width=9cm,align=left,inner sep=0.4cm},  font={\fontsize{45}{12}\selectfont},   line/.style={-latex}}
\tikzset{block/.style={fill=blue!15,draw, thick, text width=10cm,align=center,minimum width=11cm,minimum height = 4cm},font={\fontsize{45}{12}\selectfont},   
line/.style={-latex}}
\tikzset{blocks/.style={fill=yellow!20,draw, thick, text width=11cm,align=center,inner sep=0.8cm}, font={\fontsize{45}{12}\selectfont},  line/.style={-latex}}

\newcommand{\midarrow}{\tikz \draw[-triangle 90] (0,0) -- +(-.1,0);}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[ellipse, draw,text width=15cm,fill=red!15,text centered,font={\fontsize{45}{12}\selectfont}] (w1) at (-3,9) {\textbf{XYZ} \\ \vspace{0.6cm} \textit{``qwerty werwe \\[0.4cm] quiet Guard?"} };
\node[ellipse, draw,minimum width = 30cm, minimum height = 15cm,fill=red!15,font={\fontsize{45}{12}\selectfont}] (w2) at (-3,-15) {};
\node[minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 0.5cm,text centered,font={\fontsize{45}{12}}] (p) at (-3,-9) {\textbf{Output}};
\node[block1] (q) at (-9,-12) {\textit{Bran}, \textbf{\texttt{wrerw}}};
\node[block1,right=of q]  (r) {\textit{haue}, \textbf{\texttt{dfs}}};
\node[block1,below=of r]at (-9,-13) (s) {\textit{you}, \textbf{\texttt{sdf}}};
\node[block1,right= of s] (t) {\textit{bad}, \textbf{\texttt{vdxv}}};
\node[block1,below= of t] at (-9,-16) (u) {\textit{quiet}, \textbf{\texttt{dsf}}};
\node[block1,right=of u] (v) {\textit{Guard}, \textbf{\texttt{sdf}}};
\node[rectangle, draw,minimum width =15cm, minimum height =14cm] (ik) at (30,8) {}; 
\node[minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 0.5cm,text centered,font={\fontsize{100}{12}\selectfont}] (a) at (30,14) { \textbf{Process}};
\node[blocks] (b) at (30,10) {\textit{fsdfsde \\[0.4cm] you sdf \\[0.2cm] sdf?}};
\node[blocks] (c) at (30,4) {\textit{wsd sdf u \\[0.4cm] dsfsdfsd  sdfsd}};
\node[rectangle, draw,minimum width =27cm, minimum height =22cm] (jk) at (31.14,-16) {};
\node[minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 0.5cm,text centered,font={\fontsize{45}{12}\selectfont}] (d) at (30,-6.4) {\textbf{Word egdf}};
\node[block11] (d) at (24.5,-10.28) {\textit{df} = [-0.106,\\[0.4cm] 0.789, -0.130]};
\node[block11,right=of d]  (e) {\textit{fdf} = [-0.211, \\[0.4cm]-0.094, -0.246]};
\node[block11,below=of e]at (24.5,-13) (f) {\textit{you} = [0.277, \\[0.4cm]-0.049,-0.477]};
\node[block11,right= of f] (g) {\textit{df} = [-0.014, \\[0.4cm]0.387, -0.348]};
\node[block11,below= of g] at (24.5,-19.5) (h) {\textit{dfd} = [0.184, \\[0.3cm]-0.025, -0.600]};
\node[block11,right=of h] (i) {\textit{Guardfd} = [0.211, \\[0.3cm]-0.324, -0.230]};
\node[rectangle, draw,minimum width =15cm, minimum height =35cm] (lk) at (60,-5) {};
\node[minimum width = 5cm, minimum height = 0.5cm,text centered,font={\fontsize{45}{12}\selectfont}] (j) at (60,11) {\textbf{dfgh}};
\node[block] (k) at (60,7) {fgh};
\node[block] (l) at (60, 1) {Bi-hjhn};
\node[block] (m) at (60,-5) {uyi};
\node[block] (n) at (60,-11) {yuir};
\node[block] (o) at (60,-17) {tyui};
\node[rectangle, draw,minimum width =52cm, minimum height =45cm] (oo) at (43,-5) {};
\draw[-{>[width=0.3in]}, line width=6pt] (w1) -- (17,9);
\draw[-{>[width=0.3in]}, line width=6pt] (30,1) -- (30,-5);
\draw[-{>[width=0.3in]}, line width=6pt] (jk) -- (52.5,-15.7);

\begin{scope}[very thick, every node/.style={sloped,allow upside down}]
  \draw [-, line width=6pt](-3.5,-30)-- node {\midarrow} (60,-30);
  \draw[-, line width=6pt] (60,-30)-- node {\midarrow} (60,-22.5);
  %\draw (4,2)-- node {\midarrow} (-4,2);
  \draw[{<[width=0.3in]}-, line width=6pt] (-3.5,-22.5)-- node {\midarrow} (-3.5,-30);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{\textcolor{blue}{Drawere}}
\label{fig:Draweer}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]